# How to URL Rewrite in htaccess with php

Tags: .htaccess

http://npp.demo.com:8080/mydemo/current.php

above my real URL.

I want below url with hidden query string

```
http://npp.demo.com:8080/mydemo/try/current.php
```

I try diffrent type of method but no success.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/try([^/.]*)?$ $2?id=%1&file_name=$2&full_file_path=%2&one=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}


RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]*)?$ $2?id=%1&file_name=$2&full_file_path=%2&one=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{ENV:TEST} ^([^/]+)/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)try/?$ current.php?id=$1&file_name=$2&full_file_path=%2&one=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{ENV:TEST} ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/try(.*)/?$ $2?id=%1&file_name=$2&full_file_path=%2&one=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It will not fix the problem, but instead of putting `&%{QUERY_STRING}` behind a rewritten url, use the `[QSA]` flag. If I deduct it correctly, it seems to me that you are rewriting to `/current.php` instead of `/mydemo/current.php`.

Comment: Where is query string in `http://npp.demo.com:8080/mydemo/try/current.php` ?